# Rails 6 Active storage setup - NameError Exception: uninitialized constant #<Class:0x00007fddde3597d8>::Analyzable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm setting active storage with s3 in Rails 6.

- I did rails `active_storage:install` and `db:migrate`.
- In development.rb, i added:
  `config.active_storage.service = :amazon`
- I added `gem "aws-sdk-s3", require: false` in my gemfile.
- My model has this: `has_one_attached :photo`
- This is my storage.yml.

```
 test:
    service: Disk
    root: <%= Rails.root.join("tmp/storage") %>

  local:
    service: Disk
    root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>

  amazon:
    service: "S3"
    access_key_id: xxxx
    secret_access_key: xxxx
    region: xxxx
    bucket: xxxx
```

- But on calling `model.photo.attach(params[:photo'])`, i'm getting this error.
  `*** NameError Exception: uninitialized constant #<Class:0x00007fddde3597d8>::Analyzable`
- My yml seems to be correct, i already checked it in yml validator. But,
  `Rails.application.config_for(:storage)` returns {}

Any suggestions would help.

Comment: Maybe it is typo: `model.photo.attach(params[:photo'])`, there shouldn't be `'` in `params[:photo]`

Comment: Did you try restarting your server? Are your AWS credentials all correct? Did you install MiniMagic? Try stopping spring `bin/spring stop` from root of the project and restart server?

Comment: My mistake. Its a typo. I'm getting value in params['photo']. I'm restarting the server everytime i make changes in storage.yml. 
Spring is not running on my system. I have mini_magick (4.10.1).

Comment: Try running `model.photo.purge` or `model.photo.purge_later` before calling `model.photo.attach(params[:photo])` and see if it works. I don't think it'll make a difference, but try it

Comment: It came out to be an issue with my form. Thanks for help @cdadityang

Comment: @Meenakshi curious what the form issue was? I think I'm hitting the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

So I've run into that issue and for me at least it was a storage problem.

Locally in my `storage.yml` I was using:

```
local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>
```

But the folder `storage` was missing.

Creating that folder fixed that error.

Comment: Storage folder already exists for me but I'm still seeing the above issue also.